# ActiveRecord doesn't set a datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a datetime field called time in my MotionRecord model. I try to set it using this command:

```
MotionRecord.create({:time=> "2010-10-15 15:10:24", :chart_id=>1})
```

Oddly enough this results in the following input:

```
<MotionRecord id: 1, time: nil, chart_id: 1>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Edit: This is my model.

```
class MotionRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chart
  belongs_to :activity

  attr_accessor :time
end
```

and my schema

```
create_table :motion_records do |t|
  t.datetime :time
  t.integer :chart_id
  t.integer :activity_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Can you show your model code and stack log ?

Comment: The second line comes from the stack log. I am pasting my model to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to your other question. Use `attr_accessible :time` and not `attr_accessor`. See ["WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944288/warning-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set it after the create using update_attribute(:field, "value")

Comment: i'm doing that in the seed file. :-)