# Dragonfly mass-assign error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, dragonfly-gem

I've added an "avatar" to my user model (Devise) and am getting the error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: avatar`

In my user model I have added:

```
attr_accessible :avatar_uid, :avatar_name
image_accessor :avatar
```

And the form (simple_form) has :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true } and fields:

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<%= f.hidden_field :retained_avatar %>
<%= f.check_box :remove_avatar %>
```

Adding `:avatar` to `attr_accessible` solves the mass assignment error but the fields just don't get saved in the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add avatar in attr_accessible list as well in order to mass-assign it.

So just replace attr_accessible list by,

```
 attr_accessible :avatar_uid, :avatar_name, :avatar
```

**image_accessor** is provided by dragon-fly gem which provide reader/writer for listed attribute like attr_accessor.

check this out this thread to know more differnce  between attr_accessible and attr_accessor

["WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944288/warning-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes)

Comment: Infact I think you only need :avatar - dragonfly was new to me back then ;)