# Do I need a Foreign ID or a different Active Record Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I'm stumped on my Rails app. I've created 3 models: `user, event, category` that have the following associations:

```
class User
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

class Category
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :events

class Event
  attr_accessible :address, :cost, :date, :details, :end_time, :fav, :start_time, :title, :venue
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => :name #not sure if this foreign key is working
```

The idea is that `Users` create `events` that are filed under a single `category`. The categories are pre-populated so users don't get to make them, only choose which to file under.

My user and events association has been working for a while, but since I've added the category model I get a **"Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category"** error when I try to create a new event.

I've been browsing pages all day and can't seem to track the error down. I tried adding a foreign key using `belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => :name` in the `Event` class but that didn't seem to help.

Would graciously appreciate any help, solutions, and/or pointers in the right direction!

**Edit 2:** I'm pretty new at Rails, but I think I've tracked down where the problem is from the error screen. Says "**ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in EventsController#create**" and further down says "**app/controllers/events_controller.rb:58:in create**" which equates to this line of code: `@event = current_user.events.new(params[:event])`.

If I'm reading it correctly, that would mean the error occurs because I'm trying to create a new event with a `category` param passed in the hash and it doesn't know what to do with it. Unfortunately, I don't know what to do either...

**Edit 3:** As requested, here's the Event controller's create action:

```
def create
@event = current_user.events.new(params[:event])

respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at this similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944288/warning-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes

Comment: Can you tell exactly, while doing what you are getting this "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category" error.

Comment: I'm trying to add an event by "localhost:3000/events/new" which is the form I've been able to create events prior to adding the categories. Since I've added the category f.collection_select (which displays correctly) I get the error after I click the submit button. I'll edit in the form HTML

Answer (score 0):

Place the `:foreign_key => :name` in `class User` OR provide `attr_accessible` to `class User`

Comment: I don't intend to have a relation between the Users and Categories; wouldn't that establish one?

Comment: I've updated what attr_accessible `class User` already has on it

Comment: try this in the create action of your controller. @event = current_user.events.create(params[:event])

Answer (score 0):

Add :category to attr_accessible in Event model.
And using name as foreign key is a bad idea, becouse it isn't unique

For create event with relation with user and category you can do:

```
user.events.build do |event|
    event.category = category
end
```

or

```
category.events.build do |event|
    event.user =user
end
```

Also, you can use method create

Comment: I get the following error when I add :category:
`Category(#70276053732040) expected, got String(#70276029549620)`
and then it references my 'create' action in the event controller.

Comment: You should create event like `category.events.build` or `category.events.create`